# rename columns based on specific rule pandas

Tags: python, pandas

Initial df is:

```
df = 

a  a  a  a
1  2  3  4
5  6  7  8
9  1  2  3
```

---

Desired output:

```
df = 

b_1  c_1  b_2  c_2
1    2    3    4
5    6    7    8
9    1    2    3
```

I can do in a long way, like choose odd then even columns, rename them and concat. But looking for a quick solution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
df =pd.DataFrame({'a':[],'b':[],'c':[],'d':[],'e':[],'f':[],'g':[],'h':[]})
df.columns = ['b_'+str(i//2 +1) if i%2==0 else 'c_'+str((i//2 +1)) for i in range(df.shape[1]) ]
print(df.columns)
```

output:

```
Index(['b_1', 'c_1', 'b_2', 'c_2', 'b_3', 'c_3', 'b_4', 'c_4'], dtype='object')
[Finished in 2.6s]
```